# Battery Confusion

Tags: batteries

I'm very new to the electrical engineering stackexchange site, but I think that it may be an invaluable resource in the electric skateboard project that I am scoping out.

I'm currently looking into batteries. I'm entirely puzzled by the price difference on these two batteries:

- [ZIPPY Flightmax](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewitem.asp?idproduct=8586)
- [Turnigy 5800mAh](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__10895__turnigy_5800mah_8s_25c_long_lipo_pack.html)

The two batteries seem VERY similar, but the larger battery has a price that is almost double.  Can anyone explain the severe discrepancy in prices to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not similar at all.

The turnigy is a 5800mAh 8s1p battery, it means that there are 8 cells in series and the total capacity is 5800mAh. The zippy is "only" 5000mAh and it's a 6s1p, meaning there are just six cells in series.

The turnigy can nominally deliver 6.1kW when fully charged while the zippy is under 3.9kW. That's quite a difference, isn't it? The turnigy should last nearly 20% more than the zippy, that's another big difference.

To compute the power let's suppose we have a battery of capacity \$Q\$, nominal voltage \$V_N\$, nominal and maximum discharge capacity \$C_{NOM}, C_{MAX}\$. For the ZIPPY pack:

$$V_N = 22.2V\\Q=5000mAh\\C_{NOM}=25h^{-1}\\C_{MAX}=35h^{-1}$$
$$I_{NOM} = C_{NOM}\cdot Q=125A\\I_{MAX} = C_{MAX}\cdot Q=175A$$

Now since \$P=V\cdot I\$:
$$P_{NOM} = V_N\cdot I_{NOM} = 2775W\\P_{MAX} = V_N\cdot I_{MAX} = 3885W$$

Calculations for the other battery are similar as you can imagine.

**Edit**
Please note that for any application that does not consider the usage of LiPo battery an overdischarge protection circuit is **needed**. Overdischarging a LiPo *should* be harmless but you'd at least end up with a 99$ paper holder.

Comment: Thanks! Good answer. Could you explain how you found the power delivery though? I really am quite new to this.

Comment: The use would be in an electric longboard. Their motors supposedly consume quite a bit.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. Just please note that an over discharge protection circuit is needed with LiPo batteries.

Comment: @Vladimir Cravero, I think that the Cnon and Cmax numbers are confusing me. You are using them as the amount of time that the batteries can be discharged, but I think that "C" means capacity and that 25C means discharging at 25 times C.  I.E disharge current is 25XC.  A 3.9KW Lipo battery is massive energy (3 X bigger than the Prius C battery) while this battery looks smaller than my hand!

Comment: yes they are. the point is that the C thing is not rigorous at all, I mean that what "25C" means is not too clear, nor is it what C means. I randomly choose C, use your favorite letter if it helps you. And be careful: watts measure power, **not energy**. A prius battery can probably supply something around 100kW of power, and the energy stored is maybe 100+ times this small lipo.

Answer (score 1):

The first battery is a 6 cell and the second an 8 cell, so even though their amp hour capacity is much different, their total energy is different.  Also,  most of those batteries CANNOT supply the full rated amp hours at the full 25C rate, but the more expensive battery seems to claim that it is more likely to delivery what it claims. So:

Battery 1: 6 cells, 22.2 v, 5000 mAh = 111 watts nominal (Fully charged = 126 watts)

Battery 2: 8 cells, 29.6 v, 5800mAh, = 171.68 watts nominal (fully charged = 194.88 watts) and at a large discharge rate of 25C = 145,000 mA you will apparently still get most of that energy where in the first battery at that high discharge rate, you won't be able to use all of the 126 watts as some of it will be lost it heat at that high discharge rate.

I see that Vladimir Cravero also answered while I was typing this, but I think his math is wrong, (or my math is wrong)!!

Comment: Both are right, yours is nominal wattage, mine is nominal *max* wattage, I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try reading the specs again. They both differ in capacity, voltage, no. of cells, physical dimensions and more importantly the manufactures are different. I think these are acceptable reasons for a price change.